# Facebook php SDK/SQL - Get user's first status EVER

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I need help retrieving users first status EVER. Is there any chance to do it?

Now I use:

```
$result = $this->fb->api('/me/statuses?limit=1');
```

How to make it work, maybe some fql query or something? I researched many topics about this question but never found answer which worked.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: +1 because I tried to do this myself when the graph api first came out and eventually gave up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible. Your two options would be using `/me/status` and then paging back in time, or using the FQL (i.e. `/fql?q=SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid = 36902548 and time < 1310785030000 order by status_id asc`) and going back in time and/or finding the date the user joined Facebook and looking around there.

Neither of these would be very efficient, and probably impractical for a large number of users.